# Javascript RegExp verify string finishes with html open tag + anything but a tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to verify that a string ends with any open Tag followed or not by a text

for example:

```
<div>some text here
```

or

```
<span>some text here
```

should match

but

```
<div>some text here</div>
```

or

```
<h1>some text here</h1>
```

should not

I tried to come up with a solution (sorry I'm not a regex pro)

```
let anyOpenTag = '<([^/>][^>])*>';
let anyCloseTag = '</[^/>][^>]*>';
let neitherOpenNorCloseTag = `[^(${anyOpenTag}|${anyCloseTag})]`;
let regex = new RegExp(
  escapeRegExp(`${anyOpenTag}${neitherOpenNorCloseTag}*$`),
  'gi');
```

1. I set a variable "anyOpenTag" to a regex that verifies if it's an open tag like (`<p>`, `<div>`, `<span>` etc...
2. I set a variable "anyCloseTag" to a regex that verifies if it's a closing tag like (`</p>`, `</div>`, etc...)
3. I set a variable "neitherOpenNorCloseTag" that tries to combine the two and check if it's not one of them using the [^....]

finally I check if the regex match anyOpenTag + neitherOpenNorCloseTag

unfortunately it doesn't work for me, precisely the part that verifies "neitherOpenNorCloseTag"

your help is appreciated, even if you have a better regex I would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples, this snippet works:

```js
const regex = /<.*>.*<\/.*>/g

const regexString = (regex) => {
  return (s) => {
    return !s.match(regex)
  }
}

const validateString = regexString(regex)

const strings = [
  '<div>some text here',
  '<span>some text here',
  '<div>some text here</div>',
  '<h1>some text here</h1>',
]

const validated = strings.map(validateString)

console.log('Result:', validated)
```

Comment: if you add a string without an open tag at the beginning i.e: 'some random text'  to your strings array, it will be evaluated as true, which is not correct, the open tag should be always present at the beginning of the string

Comment: @medBouzid yes, I see. In the examples, you have not specified such a case, so it wasn't taken into account.

Comment: I think the title and also the first sentence in my question says it clearly even though I haven't provided an example for every possible case :)